# Typescript Array of Array of Array of Objects

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a curriculum that doesn’t need to be changed dynamically so I want to hard code it in service in my angular project.

The data is as follows:

Term 1
Term 2
Term 3

Each term has 5 grades
Each grade has 10 subjects
Each subject has 12-16 weeks depending on the term.

I want to access the data as follow

currentLesson = term.grade.subject.week.data;

To do this, I believe I need to make a Term Array which each term consists of a grade array which then each grade consists of a subject Array which then each subject Array consists of An object of week / curriculumData.

I can make the last simple Array of objects but my mind shuts down trying to do the array of Array of Array of objects.

Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: I'm assuming you really mean something like `const currentLesson = curriculum.terms[t].grades[g].subjects[s].weeks[w].data` where `t`,`g`,`s`, and `w` are numbers.  But what are you asking here... how to define interfaces for these types?  Or how to convert your curriculum data into this format?  Or something else?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In short, I don’t know how to declare an array of arrays of arrays of objects.

Comment: Right now my declaration looks like this but I’m not confident that it’s the best approach.                   interface curriculum {
    term: number;
    grade: Array<{
       id: number;
       subject: Array<{
           id: number;
           week: Array<{
                 id: number;
                 data: string;
               }>
          }>
    }>
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your 'data' is a simple string, you could simply create a multidimensional array like this:

```js
const lessons: string[][][][] = buildLessons();
const currentLesson = lessons[t][g][s][w];
```

Of course, you could replace `string` with a more complicated datatype if you wanted to, e.g.:

```js
interface Lesson {
  data: string;
  otherProperty: number;
}
const lessons: Lesson[][][][] = buildLessons();
const currentLesson = lessons[t][g][s][w];
// do something with currentLesson.data, etc
```

Alternatively, if you want to use an object structure, you could also write that out in a more readable way by splitting into separate interfaces, like so:

```js
interface Curriculum {
  term: number;
  grades: Grade[];
} 

interface Grade {
  id: number;
  subjects: Subject[];
}

interface Subject {
  id: number;
  weeks: Week[];
}

interface Week {
  id: number;
  data: string;
}

let example: Curriculum;
const currentLesson = example.grades[g].subjects[s].weeks[w].data;
```

Comment: The splitting interfaces is what I was after. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome :) In that case can you please accept the answer?